# Vector Autoregression: Difference between first-differencing, logs and logs of levels?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression

I want to use a vector autoregression in order to estimate an impulse response analysis, but I am not sure what the differences between first-differencing, logs and logs of levels are.

Is there any overview or mathematical intuition when to use logs. etc. for variables?

Comment: You may look for questions on stationarity, unit roots and differencing, and on when to use the log transformation. Quite a few such questions have been asked -- and answered -- on this site.

Comment: How are logs different from logs of levels? Did you mean diff-logs?